# SimException on proguard build, Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-proguard, simexception

I have enabled proguard for my project and I get this exception when I build signed APK

```
    Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbkq: can't find referenced method 'int zzaT(android.os.Parcel)' in program class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zzb
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbkq: can't find referenced method 'int zzaU(android.os.Parcel)' in program class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zzb
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbkq: can't find referenced method 'int zzcW(int)' in program class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zzb
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbkq: can't find referenced method 'int zzaV(android.os.Parcel)' in program class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zzc
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbkr$zza: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzd$zza
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbks: can't find referenced field 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzb zzaQy' in program class com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbks: can't find referenced method 'android.os.IBinder zzdX(java.lang.String)' in program class com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbku: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapn
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbku: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapn$zza
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbku: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapn$zzb
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbku: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapn$zzc
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbku: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapn$zzd
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbku: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapo
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbku: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapr
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbku: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapn
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbku: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapo
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbku: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapr
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbku: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapn
Warning:com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapn
W   arning:com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash: can't find referenced method 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzd zzA(java.lang.Object)' in program class com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zze
Warning:com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapn
Warning:com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash: can't find referenced method 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzc zzaab()' in program class com.google.firebase.iid.zzc
Warning:there were 45 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:there were 8 unresolved references to program class members.
Error:Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstMethodRef cannot be cast to com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstInterfaceMethodRef   
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --main-dex-list D:\Studio Workspace\JB\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\release\maindexlist.txt --output D:\Studio Workspace\JB\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\release\folders\1000\1f\main D:\Studio Workspace\JB\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar}
```

This is my build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vfirst.jb"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {    
    release {   
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'  
    }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'  
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

How do I resolve this error?
This is my proguard content`-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
    public void *(android.view.View);
    public private *;
}`