# Log4j2.8.2 SimException Issue

Tags: java, android, proguard, log4j2

I have to move log4j1.2.17 to log4j2.8.2. I did the below changes in android build.gradle for log4j2 implementation.

```
implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.8.2'
implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.8.2'
implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:2.8.2'
```

Also as explained in some of the stackoverflow, I made the proguard changes as stated below:

```
#log4j2
-dontwarn org.apache.logging.log4j.**
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class org.apache.logging.log4j.** { *; }
```

After building the project using maven, below is the stacktrace:

> [INFO] Uncaught translation error:
>   com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: ERROR in
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.convert.DateTypeConverter.fromMillis:(JLjava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Date;:
>   invoking a signature-polymorphic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26
>   (currently 13) [INFO] Uncaught translation error:
>   com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: ERROR in
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ContextDataFactory.createContextData:()Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/util/StringMap;:
>   invoking a signature-polymorphic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26
>   (currently 13)

I tried so many solution from stackoverflow, couldnt find exact solution for the same. Below are the links:

[ProGuard SimException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915959/proguard-simexception)

[SimException on proguard build, Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199589/simexception-on-proguard-build-android-studio)

Please suggest any solution which could me help me to resolve the above issue. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a lot, I got to know the issue is not with the proguard.Then I ended up saving logcat to a text file as stated in the below link:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565685/saving-logcat-to-a-text-file-in-android-device/37541596)

Hope this helps others.